# MySQL timestamp by hour?

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, hour

In my MySQL database I need to collect events of various types in *EventTable* in a resolution of hours: If the same event type occurs 750 times within the same hour, I want **one** row with that specific type and counter=750. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE EventTable (
  EventType TINYINT, EventHour HOUR, Counter INT, ...,
  UNIQUE KEY (EventType,EventHour))
```

This will give me an easy and quick way to select events by type and hour. Problem is, to the best of my knowledge, **there is no HOUR type in MySQL** that I can index by. There is DATETIME (by seconds) and there is DATE (by days)... any advice?

Comment: Hour is just number, for that you don't need another datatype .. you can store the same in number or int datatype.

Comment: Sounds good. Still, to optimize things, I need a way to convert NOW() to a number within MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT HOUR(NOW())` should do what you want

Comment: Searching further I suppose I can use: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'1000-01-01 00:00:00',NOW())`

Comment: Question is: Will `SELECT * FROM EventTable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,EventHour,NOW()) < 48` **use the index** on EventHour?